# call javascript function after another

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Can you please help answering this. Please not the contraints.

```
var myLib = {

 var callback_one = function (result_from_web_service) {
   console.log('callback_one'); 
 };

 var callback_one = function (result_from_web_service) {
   console.log('callback_two'); 
 };

 var init = function () {
   console.log('initializing...');
   async_call_one(callback_one);
   async_call_two(callback_two);
 };

 var doStuff = function () {
   console.log('doStuff is called');
 };

};

// User of my library
myLib.init();
myLib.doStuff();

// output
initializing...
doStuff is called
callback_one
callback_two

// What i need:
initializing...
callback_one
callback_two
doStuff is called
```

Constraint:

1. calling myLib.init shall not end up calling myLib.doStuff. i.e. myLib.init should be independent of myLib.doStuff
2. myLib.doStuff() should be called after myLib.init() and its callbacks are returned.

Thanks,

Comment: Make `myLib.init` accept a callback or return a promise, and either pass `myLib.doStuff` to it or work with the promise.

Comment: thanks man, can you show me an example?

Comment: There is no way you can guarantee (without additional constraint) callback_one will be executed before callback_two.

Comment: @user3624743: Here you go: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 1):

```
//You must change your API so init is async
//There is no way to have it wait until all initialization is done before it retuns
var init = function (initDone) { 
   console.log('initializing...');

   var n = 0;
   function serviceDone(){
      n++;
      if(n >= 2){ initDone() }
   }

   async_call_one(function(x){ callback_one(x); serviceDone() });
   async_call_two(function(x){ callback_two(x); serviceDone() });
};

// User of my library
myLib.init(function(){
  myLib.doStuff();
})
```

The way I parallelized those calls is very ad-hoc s not the most maintainable (there I need to keep the calls to serviceDone and the value of N in sync).. In the long run I would recommend using one of the many JS async programming libs out there.

Comment: but this would break my 1st contraint. i.e. calling init shall not end up calling doStuff. may be it is impossible?

Comment: @user3624743: Sadly it is impossible to do it in Javascript. The best you can do is have `init` receive a callback so the code calling `init` gets to decide what runs next instead of it being hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

hugomg has a good answer.

Yet I think it is really specific and could benefit a sort of workflow implementation, like this (approximately...):

```
function void() {}

var myLib = {

    var g_flow = [];

    g_flow[this.init] = [];
    g_flow[this.init]["whendone"] = this.callback_one;
    g_flow[this.init]["done"] = false;

    g_flow[this.callback_one] = [];
    g_flow[this.callback_one]["whendone"] = this.callback_two;
    g_flow[this.callback_one]["done"] = false;

    g_flow[this.callback_two] = [];
    g_flow[this.callback_two]["whendone"] = this.doStuff;
    g_flow[this.callback_two]["done"] = false;

    g_flow[this.doStuff] = [];
    g_flow[this.doStuff]["whendone"] = void;
    g_flow[this.doStuff]["done"] = false;

    var callback_one = function (result_from_web_service) {
       console.log('callback_one'); 
    };

    var callback_one = function (result_from_web_service) {
       console.log('callback_two'); 
    };

    var init = function () {
       console.log('initializing...');
    };

    var doStuff = function () {
       console.log('doStuff is called');
    };

    var flow_onward(hwnd) {
        async_call(function(){ hwnd(); myLib.flow_onward(g_flow[hwnd]["whendone"]); });
    }

    flow_onward(this.init);

};

// User of my library
myLib.init();
myLib.doStuff();
```

Doing this way you can ensure the sequentiality and expand the numbers of callback as much as you want.

ps: this code has not been tested